# Can't view new data added to table in access using vb .net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, inner-join, sql-insert

I've created a form to add in new performances to a table in access, and a way to view previous performances. However, when I go to view the table, the new performances aren't there. The view table is an inner join, whereas I'm adding the data into the 2 separate tables, is this why I can't view the update?
**View Table:**

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT ConcertMusic.ClubName, DatePerformed, Music.Piece, Artist FROM Music INNER JOIN ConcertMusic ON ConcertMusic.Piece=Music.Piece;")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub        
DgvData.DataSource = Access.DBDT
```

**Adding into first table with primary key**

```
 Dim Piece As String = TxtPiece.Text
 Dim Artist As String = TxtArtist.Text


 Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Music(Piece, Artist) VALUES ('" & Piece & "','" & Artist & "');")

 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub
```

**Adding into second table:**

```
Dim Club As String = CmbClub.Text
Dim Term As String = CmbTerm.Text
Dim Dates As String = TxtDate.Text
Dim Piece As String = TxtPiece.Text

Dim ConcertID As String = (Term.Substring(0, 1) & Dates & Club.Substring(0, 2))

Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO ConcertMusic ( ConcertID, Term, ClubName, DatePerformed) VALUES ('" & ConcertID & "','" & Term & "','" & Club & "','" & Dates & "');")
```

I know there are probably better ways to do this, and I've left the database vulnerable to SQL injection but this is for my a level coursework due in on Monday, so Id rather it be a working shell than perfect.

Comment: Is the Access database file part of your project? If so, you're probably looking at the wrong database. Read [this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) to learn how local data files are managed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yeah, it is a part of the project. But I'm viewing the table through a data grid view pulling in the data from the database, not opening the actual database through access

Comment: That doesn't rule out looking at the wrong database.  Did you follow the link I provided? By default, if you make code changes and then run the project again, any previous changes made will be lost.

Comment: If that's not the issue then it's your data access code that is wrong but you haven't shown us that.  You've hidden it inside that `Access` class.  Confirm that the issue is not as I first suggested and then debug your code properly, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through your ADO.NET code.